# tela de toque c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, navegador-de-internet

Desenvolvi essa aplicação que visualiza informações contidas num website através de windows forms e com o componente webBrowser. A aplicação funciona com o mouse perfeitamente. Quando corro numa tela touch, a aplicação simplesmente não responde aos cliques que o utilizador aplica.

Eis o código actual:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Security.Permissions;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WebsiteWrapper
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public static Timer IdleTimer = new Timer();
            const int Tempo = 90000; // 1min - represents the configured time to see if the application is in idle
            public Form1()
            {

            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            IdleTimer.Interval = Tempo;
            IdleTimer.Tick += TimesUp;
            IdleTimer.Start();
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(Application_Idle);

        }

        //avoid the page to open external links
        private void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        public void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IdleTimer.Enabled)
            {
                IdleTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        //reload de webBrowser when it reachs 1min of inactivity
        public void TimesUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.myWebsite.co.mz/index.php/pt/novo");

        }
    }

    //events messages 
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public class LeaveIdleMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2;
        const int WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A4;
        const int WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5;
        const int WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A7;
        const int WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00A8;
        const int WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN = 0x00AB;
        const int WM_NCXBUTTONUP = 0x00AC;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
        const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
        const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
        const int WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;
        const int WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208;
        const int WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B;
        const int WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C;

        // The Messages array must be sorted due to use of Array.BinarySearch
        static int[] Messages = new int[] {WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,
            WM_NCLBUTTONUP, WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCRBUTTONUP, WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN,
            WM_NCMBUTTONUP, WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCXBUTTONUP, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP,
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, WM_RBUTTONUP,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN, WM_MBUTTONUP, WM_XBUTTONDOWN, WM_XBUTTONUP};

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)  // mouse move is high volume
                return false;
            if (!Program.IdleTimer.Enabled)     // idling?
                return false;           // No
            if (Array.BinarySearch(Messages, m.Msg) >= 0)
                Program.IdleTimer.Stop();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Acho que estou perdido e de tantas pesquisas que fiz na google nada achei que me ajudou a resolver o problema. A aplicacao corre num computador com windows 10.

Comment: Você verificou se as contantes para a tela touch são as mesmas que mapeou no seu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

A tela touch externa não reconhecia os toques porque precisava instalar os drivers da tela no computador em a aplicação esta instalada.